# How to reset netstat -e counters

Tags: netstat

I would like to reset `netstat -e` counters.
How can I do it?

Renewing the network interface may reset these counters, but it is NOT an option - the networking must not be interrupted.

My OS is Windows XP

Comment: Which OS? netstat is available nearly everywhere and behaves different on every platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reset the counters in Windows without interrupting the network.